# How do I set the margins on a PDF print out of a CiviReport?

Tags: civireport, printing

How do I set the margins on a PDF print out of a CiviReport?

Things I tried: Setting these in print.css on the body element. had no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of CiviCRM 5.3 the margins on a PDF print of a CiviReport take their margins from the default PDF page format. This can be administered at:

Choose: Administer >> Communications >> Print Page (PDF) Formats

Then edit the format marked default and set the margins individually. The margins are set in the Unit of Measure of that page format.